# ASP.Net WebService automatic Encoding-Decoding

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I need to send an XML as string to a webservice i developed with ASP.Net.

To do that i encode the xml that i need to send as parameter (string) of the webserivce and then i decode it back in webservice business logic.

---

Webservice Eg :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void WebService_DoWork ( string xml )
    {
        try
        {
            MyBo bo = new MyBo ( HttpUtility.HtmlDecode ( xml ) ) ;
            bo.DoWork() ;
        }
        catch ( Exception err ) 
        {
            //Logging Here
        }
    }
```

C# Client Eg :

```
public void CallMethod ()
{
    string encodedXMLPayload = @"&lt;?xml version=&quot.." ;

    WebService client = new WebService () ;
    client.Url = @"http:\\myTestServer:port\WebService.asmx" ;

    client.WebService_DoWork ( encodedXMLPayload ) ;
}
```

Here the complete encodedXMLPayload datas :

```
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;
    &lt;RawTransactionsByAllocCode&gt;
        &lt;ReportData&gt;
            &lt;Costcenter&gt;849001&lt;/Costcenter&gt;
            &lt;TransactionID&gt;261246195&lt;/TransactionID&gt;
            &lt;TimeStamp&gt;28/01/2016 10:15:39 PM&lt;/TimeStamp&gt;
            &lt;TransType&gt;Take&lt;/TransType&gt;
            &lt;ProductName&gt;Test Product&lt;/ProductName&gt;
            &lt;SuppliersPartNo&gt;52796843&lt;/SuppliersPartNo&gt;
            &lt;Quantity&gt;5&lt;/Quantity&gt;
            &lt;MaterialNumber&gt;17096239&lt;/MaterialNumber&gt;
            &lt;DeliveryNoteNumber&gt;&lt;/DeliveryNoteNumber&gt;
            &lt;PurchaseOrderReference /&gt;
        &lt;/ReportData&gt;
    &lt;/RawTransactionsByAllocCode&gt;
```

---

If i try to call my webservice (webmethod WebService_DoWork) from that my C# client, i receive the exactly payload (still encoded) that i send and everything is right.

If i try with Postman, SoapUI or other client i get a payload that is just decoded when i receive it in webmethod (and a duble decoding may be problematic).

Here is an example of the soap request that i use with SoapUI or Postman :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tem:WebService_DoWork>
            <tem:xml>
                 &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;
                     &lt;RawTransactionsByAllocCode&gt;
                         &lt;ReportData&gt;
                             &lt;Costcenter&gt;849001&lt;/Costcenter&gt;
                             &lt;TransactionID&gt;261246195&lt;/TransactionID&gt;
                             &lt;TimeStamp&gt;28/01/2016 10:15:39 PM&lt;/TimeStamp&gt;
                             &lt;TransType&gt;Take&lt;/TransType&gt;
                             &lt;ProductName&gt;Test Product&lt;/ProductName&gt;
                             &lt;SuppliersPartNo&gt;52796843&lt;/SuppliersPartNo&gt;
                             &lt;Quantity&gt;5&lt;/Quantity&gt;
                             &lt;MaterialNumber&gt;17096239&lt;/MaterialNumber&gt;
                             &lt;DeliveryNoteNumber&gt;&lt;/DeliveryNoteNumber&gt;
                             &lt;PurchaseOrderReference /&gt;
                         &lt;/ReportData&gt;
                     &lt;/RawTransactionsByAllocCode&gt;
             </tem:xml>
        </tem:WebService_DoWork>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So i would like to know why of that strange behaviour, may be that the C# client encode it again (under the hood) because ASP.Net automatically decode it?

Answer (score -1):

XML tags do not get encoded. Only the text between XML tags needs to be encoded. Use the actual greater than and less than symbols `<` `>` and quotes `"`. When you are writing the XML tag. You only need to encode the "values" of the XML tags like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootElement>
    <ChildElement>
        I need to encode quotes &quote; and less than/greater than symbols &lt; &gt; because this is not in a tag
    </ChildElement>
    <ChildElement>
        <DeeperChildElement some-attribute="these quotes aren't encoded">
            Special Characters here need to be encoded
        </DeeperChildElement>
    </ChildElement>
</RootElement>
```

Comment: AFAIK Soap payload need to be encoded, what i see seems that asp.net webservice and visual studio client (generated from a wsdl) automatically encode-decode the payload, so my explicit decode is redundant